# Choosing where to install python module

Tags: python, module

I have an old version of PyML, 7.10, and I want to install the new version 7.11.

To do this I downloaded PyML and ran setup.py.

However, when I run

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

The result is:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyML-0.7.11-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyML-0.7.11-py2.7.egg-info
```

This seems fine and dandy, but running

```
print PyML.__file__
```

tells me that python looks for PyML in the folder

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyML/
```

not

`/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyML-0.7.11-py2.7.egg-info` where it was written, according to setup.py

Therefore I want to change the install path to `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyML/`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already is installed there. The `.egg-info` file simply gives setuptools more information about the package such as version, requirements, etc. and should not be moved from there.

Comment: But when I write print PyML.__version__ it still says 7.10 and the files in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyML/` are all from Nov 30 09:42, which I suspect is when I installed 7.10. Therefore I suspect the install did nada.

Comment: Did you check what the value is in the source?

Comment: Ignore last comment, the dates are probably when the guy made the files, because the folders are updated today, the files way earlier.

Comment: `PyML.__version__` is not in setup.py.

Comment: But when you said check the source I looked in setup.py and there one line said: version = "0.7.11". Are there other ways to check the source?